# Predicting Intent to do X with a confidence score or intent percentage score?

Tags: logistic-regression

I have a data set like:

```
did_purchase  action_1_30d action_2_20d action_2_10d ....
   False            10          20            100
   True            ....etc
```

Where `did_purchase` shows whether the customer purchased or not, and the columns indicate the volume of actions taken before the purchase (or non-purchase) event.

So, for the first row the customer did 10 of action_1 within 30 days of the purchase event, but didn't purchase in the end.

I have been using sklearn's LogisticRegression to predict the `did_purchase` false/true, and can get about 89% accuracy, which is nice.

However, I'd like a percentage intent score instead. So it could say `user-321 has a 46% chance of purchasing in the next 10 days.`

What would be a good algo/approach for this?

Comment: You mention 89% accuracy. What is the distribution of class labels? Is there a class imbalance? If so, accuracy may not be the right metric here.

Comment: Sorry I meant F1 is 0.89. Class labels were imbalanced 1% Yes - 99% No but I SMOTE'd them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the probabilities output by `LogisticRegression`s [`predict_proba` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba).

Almost all classifiers give you a probability in sklearn. One exception is the support vector classifier which will give you a points distance to the decision hyperplane, which can be interpreted as a confidence (you can get probabilities for the support vector classifier, but it is through a computationally costly cross validation process).